# IBM MQ Kubernetes Helm kdb

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-mq, helm3, mtls, helm-tls

I have a Kubernetes IBM MQ deployment using  ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev helm chart following this [link](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ibm-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev/4.1.2).

1. Suppose I have a kdb in the Kubernetes's ibm pod. Now I want to add client cert to the key database. But I don't want to access the bash of the pod and execute IBM commands such as "runmqakm -cert -add".
2. I also want to execute some commands like "SET CHLAUTH ... " but similar to the part (1), without accessing the bash.

Does anyone have any suggestion that how can I solve these problems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of IBM MQ?

Comment: @JoshMc 9.1.5.0. ibmcom/mq:latest image

Comment: Not sure about the kdb part, you could define a service to run a script to import the cert, services run at start up if you set them to `CONTROL(QMGR)`.  This link shows how to execute MQSC commands at startup: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=commands-automatic-configuration-from-mqsc-script-startup

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks. I think the link you've offered works when the pod starts up, right? What if I want to make a change while the pod is working? Suppose we have a running IBM pod and then I want to change the configuration by some commands like "SET CHLAUTH ... "

Comment: @JoshMc Even if there is any framework in python that supports and perform "runmqsc ... " commands would be a great solution.

Comment: You can connect as a client to the queue manager using runmqsc -c to run MQSC commands.

Comment: @JoshMc This way needs accessing the bash of the pod, right? Is there any other way that can execute or run those commands not accessing the shell/ bash of the pod?

Comment: @JoshMc Sorry for asking a lot of questions. Just want to check that I am doing right. So there is no way that I could change my queue managers and channels' configuration **NOT** accessing the shell/bash

Comment: As a client means you would connect over the network.

Comment: @JoshMc Ok Thanks.

Comment: You can download the ReDist client which includes runmqsc for windows or Linux

Comment: @JoshMc Can runmqakm commands be executed similarly?  Not from the client bash and using [pcf](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=commands-introduction-mq-programmable-command-formats) commands of ibm mq.

Comment: No not directly.   You could define a service which could execute a command and then start the service.

Comment: @JoshMc Thank you.