# Creating ibm queue on container startup

Tags: ibm-mq, testcontainers

I use TestContainers with ibm mq image in it. Through config I set host, port, user=app, default passw0rd, manager = QM1. I also have more custom queues and besides default DEV.QUEUE.1 - 3 ,created by container, I gotta start up mine. I found such operator like withCommand, accepting String argument, and try to set it like
`.withCommand("sh","-c","runmqsc QM1 | define qlocal(LQ1) | end")` https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=75-creating-queue-called-lq1
Unfortunately, it seems not starting with it.

My full snap of code related:

```
 @Container
    static GenericContainer<?> mqContainer = new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("ibmcom/mq"))
            .withEnv("LICENSE", "accept")
            .withEnv("MQ_QMGR_NAME", "QM1")
     /*       .withCommand("sh","-c","runmqsc")*/
            
            .withExposedPorts(1414)
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.HALF_DAYS))
            .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log));
```

Comment: I suppose I should enter valid command on startup time to set custom queue and grant app user needed privileges for it.

Comment: This let's you run MQSC commands at startup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70480034/ibm-mq-kubernetes-helm-kdb#comment124606341_70480034

Comment: Your command should be more like this `.withCommand("sh","-c","echo 'define qlocal(LQ1)' | runmqsc QM1")`

Comment: Command does not work and container  hangs forever . Writing extra script for configuring a queue seems incredibly inconvinient way of configuration.

Answer (score 2):

ibmcom/mq image already covers this scenario. Create a mqsc script with all custom resources. Copy this script in /etc/mq folder. All resources defined in script will be created on startup.

See [Customizing the queue manager configuration](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/master/docs/usage.md#customizing-the-queue-manager-configuration) for details.

Answer (score 1):

## Your problem

Presumably you want `.withCommand()` to override the default `CMD` of the Dockerfile. But, since the IBM MQ Dockerfile uses an `ENTRYPOINT`, I would guess that, instead of overriding the command, it will be appending the parameters as arguments after the command specified in the `ENTRYPOINT`.
This blog explains it well (but has some mistakes): https://www.bmc.com/blogs/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint/

It seems you understand that you need to use piping to get the "`define qlocal(LQ1)`" into `runmqsc`, but you haven't quite grasped how piping works and unfortunately what you have written is not correct, so I would recommend you find some more information on it.

## A solution

You can use `mqContainer.execInContainer("bash", "-c", "echo 'define qlocal(LQ1)' | runmqsc QM1")` instead of the `.withCommand()` line. However you will need to run it after you start the container and wait until the container is up and MQ is running, which can be done by repeatedly calling `mqContainer.execInContainer("chkmqready")` until it has a return code of 0. Just like the tests for the container does in its Go code: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/d7c7b52492c6b1ae600bf3b8ccd9724ffd45e361/test/docker/docker_api_test_util.go#L634
There is probably a more elegant way to wait for the startup using https://www.testcontainers.org/features/startup_and_waits/ but I will leave that to you if desired.

## Alternate solution

Build a personal version of the MQ container yourself. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=image-building-sample-configured-mq-queue-manager